# Chartjs barchart generate data for an array dataset

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I want to generate some Datasets for my Barchart but i dont know why its always displayed 'statement expected' at the round bracket before the return.

```
function generateDataSets() {
    const returnValue = Array.from(new Array(5){
        return {
            name: 'Land',
            people: 200,
            backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd"]
        };
    })
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what data you're trying to generate but if you want to use the method [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), your code could look as follows:

```js
function generateDataSets() {
  return Array.from(new Array(5), (o, i) => ({
    name: 'Land',
    people: (i + 1) * 100,
    backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd"]
  }));
}

console.log(generateDataSets());
```